# Selenium IE driver : How to click a link with href value

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, playframework, driver

I used in a selenium test to test my play framework application.

My link is define like this :

```
<a href="#tabs-blacklist">&{'transaction.tab.blacklist'}</a>
```

My test is :

```
click('//a[@href='#tabs-blacklist']')
```

But each time I have object not found with IE driver, but it is ok with firefox.
Does somebody know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a css based locator:

```
click("css=a[href='#tabs-blacklist']")
```

from the Java Api http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/